# How could I make this active onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

```
var span = document.getElementById('loading_dots');

var int = setInterval(function() {
    if ((span.innerHTML += '●').length == 4) 
        span.innerHTML = '';
}, 400);

(function(){
    var loading_dots = document.getElementById("loading_dots"),

      show = function(){
        loading_dots.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(hide, 5000); // 5 seconds
      },

      hide = function(){
        loading_dots.style.display = "none";
      };

    show();
})();
```

How can I make it so loading_dots start on the click of a button, and re-activates everytime I click the button? the bottom function is to stop it after 5 seconds, maybe could merge it into one function?

**Needs to work for 3 seperate buttons and relaunch on click of each, also needs to display inside of `<span class="loading_dots" id="loading_dots"></span>` any method is fine, css, jquery, or javascript**

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for most of your code?

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons? Do you have multiple loading elements? If so, how are they related? Are the dots *inside* the buttons? Are inside some common parent? What's the general idea?

Comment: I have a few modals lazy loading iframes that resize the modal on load i want to show the loading dots so people know it's not finished loading, sometimes it takes a couple seconds for it to resize, example of 3 buttons not relaunching https://jsfiddle.net/jqt6pugz/

Comment: Ah, so you have multiple *Load* buttons but only one "visual element" to picture that something is loading

Comment: Exactly! I will edit the question to show I want it to work with multiple buttons, thought I could just add more button id's and it would work for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a jQuery version:

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.loader = function( options ) {
      var settings = $.extend({
            text:"●",
            spn: undefined
        }, options );
        
        
        $.each(this, function(){
        var btn = this;      
        var int;
        var spn;
        if (settings.spn === undefined) {
         spn = $("<span/>" , { "class":"loading_dots" });
         $(btn).append(spn);
        } else {
          spn= $(settings.spn);
         }
         var show = function(){
         btn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
         clearInterval(int);
         spn.show();
         int = setInterval(function() {
         if ((spn[0].innerHTML += settings.text).length == 4) 
           spn.html("");
        }, 400);
         setTimeout(hide, 5000); // 5 seconds
        }
        
        var hide = function (){
        spn.hide();
        btn.removeAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
        clearInterval(int);
        }
        
        btn.addEventListener("click", show);
       });
    };
 
}( jQuery ));

// now bind it by its class, this only need to be run once every time new button is added to the html
$(".btn").loader({spn:".loading_dots"});

// and you could also specify the text by 
// $(".btn").loader({text: "*"});
```

```css
.loading_dots {
color:red;
display:none;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<span class="loading_dots"></span>
<button class="btn" type="button" >
submit
</button>


<button class="btn" type="button" >
submit
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery is fine, this code works really good but it's not working when I put more than one button id in to launch it, I have 3 seperate buttons that need to activate the dots

Comment: cool, only issue now is it has to display inside the <span class="loading_dots"></span> every time, is it easy to move it to display in the span over the button?

Comment: so you want to have only one span for all buttons? or one for each button but it should be over the button?

Comment: Your code works perfectly but instead of displaying the dots inside the loading_dots span it displays them in the buttons, each button should display the dots in the loading_dots span only, the span is a php include in my site that is shown when each modal opens, but each modal is triggered by a different button click, your previous code showed the dots in the span fine but the new one the loading_dots span is missing

Comment: the previous code was great it just didn't work for the other 2 buttons, and this one works for the other 2 buttons but doesn't display it in the span

Comment: ok now you can specify the loeder span if you want. by executeing $(".btn").loader({spn:".loading_dots"});

Comment: np glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an event listener for a button click, just select the buttons, and add the listeners in a loop:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", myFunc));
```

Alternatively, listen for any click, then check if the event's target is a button:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") myFunc());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS for the most part of your code, and than simply toggle a `show` class on the parent `#loading` element:

```js
const Loading = () => {
  let tOut = null;
  const el = document.querySelector("#loading");
  const show = () => {
    el.classList.add('show');
    tOut = setTimeout(hide, 5000);
  };  
  const hide = () => {
    el.classList.remove('show');
    clearTimeout(tOut);
  };
  return {
    show,
    hide
  };
};


const loadingDots = Loading();
const loadBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.load');

[...loadBtns].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', loadingDots.show));
// you can always use loadingDots.hide() to hide when needed (before the 5sec ticks out)
```

```css
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#loading.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {opacity: 1;}
}
#loading i:after {content: "\25cf";}
#loading i { opacity: 0; animation: blink 1.2s infinite; }
#loading i:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s; }
#loading i:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s; }
```

```html
<div id="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>

<button class="load">LOAD</button>
<button class="load">LOAD</button>
<button class="load">LOAD</button>
```

Comment: If this could be displayed over an iframe instead of the whole page it would be perfect for what I'm trying to do, is that an easy change to make?

Comment: tried to apply this to see what it looks like inside of a div, looks great but only works on one modal, any clue why that is? also noticed the other answers are only working for the modal that is closest to the top of the page too, it relaunches for that 1 modal but nothing on the other 2

Comment: possibly needs to find the closest <div id="loading"> and activate?

Answer (score 1):

A plain javascript version with the option to programmatically/manually stop displaying the loading dots. Just pass the id of the parent element you want the loading to be attached to. By default the loading will be appended to the parent but you can optionally pass an object as the last parameter with a [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) property.

```js
function removeLoading(id) {
  var parent = document.getElementById(id);
  var spans = parent.getElementsByClassName("loading_dots");
  while (spans.length > 0) {
    var span = spans[0];
    if (span.dataset.timerId) {
      clearTimeout(span.dataset.timerId);
    }
    span.remove();
  }
}

function addLoading(id, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var parent = document.getElementById(id);
  var existingSpans = parent.getElementsByClassName("loading_dots");
  if (existingSpans.length > 0) {
    removeLoading(id);
  }
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("class", "loading_dots");
  if (options.timerId) {
    span.dataset.timerId = options.timerId;
  }
  parent.insertAdjacentElement(options.position || "beforeend", span);
  setInterval(function () {
    if ((span.innerHTML += '●').length == 4)
      span.innerHTML = '';
  }, 400)
}

function addLoadingWithTimeout(id, ms, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var timerId = setTimeout(function () { removeLoading(id) }, ms);
  options.timerId = timerId;
  addLoading(id, options);
}
```

```html
<p id="load1">Load 1 - Will stop automatically in 3 seconds after starting. </p>
<button onclick="addLoadingWithTimeout('load1', 3000)">Start Load 1</button>
<button onclick="removeLoading('load1')">Stop Load 1</button>

<p id="load2">Load 2 - Only manual Stop </p>
<button onclick="addLoading('load2')">Start Load 2</button>
<button onclick="removeLoading('load2')">Stop Load 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. on the HTML side, you just pass the event to the button that you want and then the id, as a string, of the span/div where you want the load icons to appear.

HTML:

```
  <button id="btn" onclick="load(event, 'loadDiv')">Load</button>
  <div>
    <span id="loadDiv"></span>    
  </div>
```

Below, we are getting the btn id from event so you don't have to manually pass it everytime. Then we are defining function for the innerhtml icons. Lastly, we are running the showIcon function every .4s and then clearing the interval after 5 seconds.

JS:

```
function load(e, location) {
  var btn = document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id)
  var loadDiv = document.getElementById(location)

  function showLoad() {
    if (loadDiv.innerHTML.length < 3) {
      return loadDiv.innerHTML += '●'
    }
    loadDiv.innerHTML = ''
  }

  (function() {
    var loadIcons = setInterval(function() {
      showLoad()
    }, 400)

    var clear = setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(loadIcons)
    }, 5000)
  })()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can define your code in a function and add click handler to the button.

```
function myFunc() {
 var span = document.getElementById('loading_dots');

 var int = setInterval(function() {
     if ((span.innerHTML += '●').length == 4) 
         span.innerHTML = '';
 }, 400);

 (function(){
     var loading_dots = document.getElementById("loading_dots"),

       show = function(){
         loading_dots.style.display = "block";
         setTimeout(hide, 5000); // 5 seconds
       },

       hide = function(){
         loading_dots.style.display = "none";
       };

     show();
 })();
}

document.getElementById("myBtn1").addEventListener("click", myFunc); 
document.getElementById("myBtn2").addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

Comment: Awesome it works but do you know how I can make it work for more than 1 button? so when I click a different button that also links to myFunc it will restart?

Comment: more than one buttons can be added by adding click handler with each of them. Try it out. I just edited the answer above.

Comment: works well but the dots start speeding up after clicked a couple times? https://jsfiddle.net/jqt6pugz/1/

Comment: is it possible for you to disable other buttons when you have clicked one  button. https://jsfiddle.net/snehansh/9t1r5fev/4/  . If not I would suggest, to have the timeout logic to be in a separate function, and execute it after a button click, and use a flag to track if the timeout has expired. Basically we dont want timeout to run more than once, even if a previous timeout has not expired.